# Content-Security-Policy header not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, axios, content-security-policy

I'm trying to make CSP to work using headers, I'm setting the CSP config to Axios headers (not sure if this is the correct way!).

```json
{
  "Content-Security-Policy": "script-src-attr 'self';"
}
```

It only works when using HTML `meta` and I need it to work using headers.

```html
  <meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="script-src-attr 'self';"
  />
```

How can I get headers to work as meta tags?

Comment: You need to configure your server to add the CORS _response_ headers

Comment: So it's not at axios ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant CSP not CORS in my original comment, but the prinicpal is the same. The CSP header is in the reponse from the server. As far as I'm aware Axios is a HTTP client and can only set _request_ headers, not _repsonse_ headers.

Comment: That does make more sense I guess, adding headers to request felt weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why CSP isn't working on Axios is because it should be on the backend API header, **not on the frontend** requests.

Backend API should be sending

```json
{
  "Content-Security-Policy": "script-src-attr 'self';"
}
```

An alternative way is by adding meta to HTML.

```html
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src-attr 'self';"
/>
```

If you implement CSP rules only on the frontend of your website or application, it can help protect against certain types of attacks, such as inline script injections or unauthorized content loading from external sources. However, it's important to keep in mind that CSP is not a complete solution to web application security.

One potential drawback of implementing CSP only on the frontend is that it can be bypassed if an attacker is able to find a vulnerability in your backend API. For example, if your API allows a user to submit arbitrary HTML content that is later displayed on the frontend, an attacker could inject malicious code in that content and bypass the CSP restrictions.